# celery fails with ECONNREFUSED after migrating from heroku to beanstalk

Tags: python, heroku, redis, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing python application using celery in heroku which I'm trying to migrate to aws beanstalk. In the heroku configuration, I'm having a web worker and celery processes. I have a redis add-on for celery to use as a broker.

As part of the migration, I'm also running a redis server on the beanstalk instance. I'm running redis and celery through beanstalk ebextensions postprocessing as recommended in some of the stackverflow posts. The redis server is running fine, which I verified through redis-cli.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-170 ~]$ ./redis-cli ping
PONG
```

Celery also starts and runs the worker processes fine.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-170 ~]$ ps -ef | grep celery
nobody   20165  2765  0 05:33 ?        00:00:05 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
nobody   20171 20165  0 05:33 ?        00:00:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
nobody   20172 20165  0 05:33 ?        00:00:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
nobody   20173 20165  0 05:33 ?        00:00:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
nobody   20174 20165  0 05:33 ?        00:00:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
nobody   20175 20165  0 05:33 ?        00:00:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
nobody   20176 20165  0 05:33 ?        00:00:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python run_celery.py -A nekt.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --maxtasksperchild=2 --autoscale=12,6 --beat
ec2-user 21392 18509  0 06:43 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto celery
```

In my application celery was already configured to use the REDIS_URL, as shown below (from my celery_config.py)

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
```

REDIS_URL is defined through aws beanstalk config parameter as redis://localhost:6379/0

The celery worker log file form /var/log shows that celery is connecting to redis on the local host.

```
[2016-08-31 05:33:50,772: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2016-08-31 05:33:50,778: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-08-31 05:33:51,782: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-08-31 05:33:51,788: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ip-172-31-3-170 ready.
```

However whenever a celery task gets invoked from the python code it returns with socket error 111 ECONNREFUSED. Here's the snippet from /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.444874 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268] mod_wsgi (pid=21707): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/manage.py'.
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.444919 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.444939 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445330 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445343 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445359 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445368 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445378 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445384 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445392 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445397 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445406 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445411 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445419 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445424 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445432 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445438 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445456 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445463 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/current/app/nekt/usercontacts/usercontacts_api.py", line 996, in upload_notify
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445674 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     notify_logs_upload.delay((post_data, result_dict['uid']))
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445686 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 453, in delay
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445866 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445876 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 565, in apply_async
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445888 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.445894 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 354, in send_task
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446029 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446039 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 310, in publish_task
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446154 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     **kwargs
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446164 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 172, in publish
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446288 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446297 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 457, in _ensured
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446523 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     interval_max)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446534 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 369, in ensure_connection
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446548 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446554 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 246, in retry_over_time
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446643 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446651 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 237, in connect
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446663 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     return self.connection
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446668 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 742, in connection
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446677 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     self._connection = self._establish_connection()
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446682 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 697, in _establish_connection
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446690 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446695 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446755 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     conn = self.Connection(**opts)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446764 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446948 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     self.transport = create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.446957 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 285, in create_transport
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.447024 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.447034 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.447045 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268]     raise socket.error(last_err)
[Wed Aug 31 06:50:48.447063 2016] [:error] [pid 21707] [remote 49.206.126.173:6268] error: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
```

If I try to check the status of celery by running "celery status" from /opt/python/run/venv/bin, that too returns the same status.

I've tried running redis with unix domain sockets, using amazon sqs as the broker and all of them give the same error. Not sure what I'm missing out!!!